# How to verify Domain Ownership

Tags: php, mysql, dns, cname

I am working on a site where people will submit their domain, And I want to know how will they confirm/verify their domain by DNS records. My site is in PHP

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at the use of CNAME's. Getting users to create custom CNAME's on their DNS records, and having your site try to access these is one way of verifying the ownership of a domain.

Another would be a bit more work, but getting users to add a Meta tag to their site, and again have your page attempt to access and read this Meta information to prove that they have access to the page - Thus verifying ownership.

UPDATE:

**dns-get-record**

[Please see HERE for PHP doccumentation on getting and checking the DNS records (CNAME being one of these)](http://php.net/manual/en/function.dns-get-record.php)

Comment: A TXT record, containing a unique key, would probably be a better option IMO. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_DNS_record_types

Comment: I agree with the comment above, It depends on your current knowledge. If it's minimal then using a TXT record would be a lot more straight forward and as shown there are several resources that make this process clear and easy to do.

Comment: @Luke But If users only have domain not hosting then How will they upload or add meta tag files. And can you explain How can i access CNAME record of a domain.

Comment: Your point about Meta tags is correct, it is a method that some use but you're right without access to the actual hosting for the content they wouldn't easily be able to do this. However:      

http://support.google.com/a/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=47283

Shows you how to access your CNAME records. This is done through the actual Domain host rather than hosting.

Comment: @Luke I got that but the main problem is how will I access to those CNAME Records to verify the domain.

Comment: If you take a look at this PHP doccumentation: http://php.net/manual/en/function.dns-get-record.php 

     It shows you how to query the DNS records (CNAME being one of these) - Hope this helps.