# How to verify Android / iOS mobile app Ownership

Tags: php, android, ios, dns, cname

I am working on a site where people will submit their mobile app package names, And I want to know how will they confirm/verify their App, I saw a solution in [How to verify Domain Ownership](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16634622/how-to-verify-domain-ownership) to use DNS records, but

1 - I dont know if Mobile App servers use DNS record
2 - I dont know how to use this examples http://php.net/manual/en/function.dns-get-record.php in PHP to confirm the CNAME if Mobile Apps can have CNAME in their Servers.
3 - Are there any pros and cons to using this.

Comment: Although it is suggested that bundle IDs in iOS (and presumably Android, I don't know) adopt a reverse DNS name format (e.g. com.acmecorp.someapp) this is just an attempt to reduce collisions.  There is no actual linkage to the DNS system.  AFAIK there is no API available to verify that someone is the owner of an app.  To do so in the Apple world the owner would need to create an AppStore Connect account that had permissions to log in and see the apps in the account.  This is how AppAnnie collects my sales data for reporting.

Comment: @paulw11 Okay thanks for the feed back, but do you know any means I can validate.

Comment: As far as I know you would need to ask the user for a login to their AppStore connect/playstore account and verify it that way